# Codeigniter - Query inside foreach

Tags: codeigniter, foreach, comments

So i'm using latest Codeigniter and my problem is that i have this situation where i should use query inside foreach in controller. I have view that shows all production orders in one list, and i want all user made comments and notes underneath them from other table. Quite general situation in coding, but how i should do this with Codeigniter, cause you should keep your SQL clauses in Models.

Before i just fork raw SQL inside controller, i wanted to ask what is more gentle and proper way to achieve this. Thanks!

**Controller**

```
<?php
public function show()
{    
  $this->load->database();

  $this->load->model('report_model');
  $this->load->helper('url');

  $data['productionOrders'] = $this->report_model->getAllProductionOrders();
  $this->load->view('all_reports', $data);
}
?>
```

**Model**

```
<?php
function getAllProductionOrders()
{
  $this->db->select(*);
  $this->db->from('dbo.QualityControl_ProductionOrders');

  $query = $this->db->get();

  return $query->result();
}
?>
```

**View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>

 <body>

  <?php
    foreach ($productionOrdersas $row)
    {
  ?>

  <div> 
    ProdNo: <?php echo $row->Prodno; ?>
    Descriptions: 
    Hours:
    etc etc etc etc
  </div>

  [I want here comments and all user made notes]

  <?php
    }
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make an effort to avoid spinning over a result set with additional queries like that..imagine if you had 500 production orders. That's 501 queries to make a simple report

Instead, use a join & parse your results either by only printing out the header info once or using Underscore.php to make a nested result, as demonstrated here:

http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/08/no-more-machine-gunning-use-underscore-php

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you asking but try this -

In controller ,

```
    $data['productionOrders'] = $this->report_model->getAllProductionOrders();

    foreach($data['productionOrders']['id'] as $id)
    {
         $data['comment'][$id] = $this->report_model->getCommantsByOrderId($id);
    }
```

Comment: That's a big no-no. You should never fire queries inside a loop. Instead one should consider joining. Look at @jmadsen's answer and the link